# Constand output voltage from batteries / rechargable batteries

Tags: voltage, batteries, voltage-regulator

I'm trying to make myself a battery pack for my DSLR camera.

The original battery of the camera has **7.2 V** and **1200 mAh**.

I've also bought a coupler ( a dummy batterie for external DC input ) which has a AC/DC adapter with **8.4 V** and **2000 mA** output.

So I am pretty sure, the camera can hadle anything between **7.2 V** and **8.4 V** input voltage.

I was thinking of using two 6x AA battery clips.

So if I wire the battery clips like so ( seriel & parallel ):

```
[##]   <--  AA battery


+--[##]---[##]---[##]---[##]---[##]---[##]--+
|                                           |
+--[##]---[##]---[##]---[##]---[##]---[##]--+-----  (+)
|                                                         INPUT
+-------------------------------------------------  (-)
```

...I should either get:

**A**. Using normal AA batteries:

```
6 x 1.5 V = 9 V
```

**B**. Using rechargeable AA batteries:

```
6 x 1.2 V = 7.2 V
```

So is there an effective way I can get a constant output with anything between **7.2 V** and **8.4 V** ??

thank you.

Comment: Sounds like it is expecting a Li-ion 2-cell battery. Why not use that?

Comment: I'd like to use AA batteries because in case of an "emergency situation" they are the most commonly used ones for my "survival" devices. That way I don't have to carry different types of batteries and chargers for them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a consistent output voltage over the life of the battery, you will have to use a voltage regulator.  In the case of the "normal" or alkaline battery, each cell will have a cutoff voltage of around 1V when finished.  So, over the life of the battery, you need to take this 6-9V input and convert it to a constant 7.2V.  This will require a buck-boost switching regulator to accomplish.

Comment: Or simply take a pack of 4 batteries and use a simpler "DC boost" regulator (take an adjustable one, rated for >= 3A, not to need cooling). You'll have to maybe bring 2 packs (4 batteries vs 6 batteries will last shorter), but it's easier to charge them (chargers usually offer 4 slots).

Comment: @OlafM Agreed that there are simpler ways to do this, but I think if we are to recommend a different solution than the OP proposed, it would be wiser to place all 12 batteries in series and buck from there.  Buck regulators tend to be easier to design and stabilize than other switching topologies, and the buck action will decrease the overall current draw on the battery pack.

Comment: Thank you for that solution ! I came across buck boost converters too. I've ordered this one http://www.ebay.de/itm/331215038909?_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT

Comment: Is this suitable for my application ? And the reason I've chosen 2x 6 AA batteries is, that this setup fits most in the project box I've used. I also can fit two 8x AA battery holders inside it. It is also possible for me to put 3x 6 AA battery holders inside it, where one of them is actually two 3 AA battery holders. How can I calculate the most effective setup ??

Comment: That isn't a true buck-boost.  It's a two stage design; non-synchronous boost followed by non-synchronous buck.  The IC on the left is Nat Semi (now TI) LM2577S.  This boosts the input voltage (your battery voltage) to ~28V.  Then the LM2596S bucks that to your programmed output based on the pot on the bottom edge of the board.  It SHOULD work for your application, but without seeing schematics/BOM, it's hard to say for certain.

Answer (score 0):

Your original battery of 7.2V might be a 2-cell Litium based cell or a 6-cell NiMh. I don't know.

The important thing to remember is that written voltages of the cell packs are "nominal". This is explained in a Texas Instruments application note SNVA533. Here is a picture of the nominal voltage, here called MPV (mid-point voltage) from the application note:

[image]

As you can see the nominal voltage is in the middle between the charged and discharged state of the battery cell.

In the application note there is also a picture of discharge curves for Li-Ion and NiMh:

[image]

The nominal voltage of the Li-Ion cell would be at 3.6V and for the NiMh at 1.25V, approximately. A fully charged Li-Ion cell would have voltage of 4.2V (depends on make and model) and the NiMh something close to 1.5V. This tells us that:

```
Li-Ion 2-cell voltage, fully charged = 2 x 4.2 = 8.4V
NiMh 6-cell voltage, fully charged = 6 x 1.5 = 9V
```

Your question was:

> So is there an effective way I can get a constant output with anything between 7.2 V and 8.4 V

Yes, with a regulator. But since this is a battery powered device it already has regulators built in! :) Otherwise it couldn't handle the variations from the original battery.

So what would be best, the Alkalines or the NiMhs? The Alkalines have a steeper discharge curve but of course have disadvantage of being non-rechargable. The NiMh have flatter discharge curve wich is quite similar to the ones of Li-Iion.

The problem I see with using NiMhs are that if your camera has short bursts of high energy consumption the high internal resistance of the cells might lower the cell-pack ouput voltage too much. This will probably trigger a low-battery warning.

Also if you pick the NiMhs directly from the charger and into the camera, the total voltage (9V) might be a bit too high for the camera to handle. This is also true for the Alkalines which will have an even higher voltage when fresh. I would suggest trying this with 5 Alkalines in series for a start.

Comment: Thank you. Yes you are right, I don't want to connect the batteries directly to the camera, therefore I came up using this buck boost converter, to stabilize the output of the battery pack to anything between 7.2 V and 8.4 V. http://www.ebay.de/itm/331215038909?_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT

Comment: Yes, but you understand that the camera already has regulators built in to handle the original batterys variations?

Comment: yes, but the original battery is just 7.2 V as i mentioned. I know the coupler goes up to 8.4 V, and the camera can handle it. but what if i need to use lets say a 10x AA bat. holder ? then the camera would have to handle 12V to 15V... I want to play safe, and integrate my own buck boost converter, just in case. that way i also can use the battery pack for other applications, since i can trim the output voltage by myself :)